# Xcode iOS 6 modal view shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations not working

Tags: xcode, view, ios6, orientation, modalviewcontroller

I wrote this part of code in appDelegate class to control the orientations of my application.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

    if (self.window.rootViewController) {
        UIViewController* presented = [[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
        orientations = [presented supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
    return orientations;
}
```

And I use this code to lock my orientation in portrait.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

This works on all of my ViewController pushed by the NavigationViewController but not on the ViewController presented by modal (my modal view doesn't seem to overwrite this code).

Example of code doesn't work when the ViewController is presented by modal. My ViewController (modal view) is still in portrait orientation.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```